# What is wrong with this code no matching function for call to?

Tags: c++

what is wrong with this code ?
no matching function for call to fun1(z*)

```
int  fun1(int &z)
{
return z+4;
}
int  fun2(int & z)
{
return z*3;
}
void main()
{
int b=6;
int m=fun1(fun2(b));
}
```

Comment: The function declaration `int a fun1(int &z)` isn't legal because you can't have `a fun1` there. You should just put the name of the function, which looks like it's `fun1`.

Comment: and `fun1` should take `z` by value or `const &`

Comment: yes this the proble how to fix it

Comment: Where does the `a` come from?

Comment: sorry there is no a just int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-const references can't bind to rvalues. In other words, `fun2` returns a *temporary* integer, which can't be used as argument to `fun1`, because it expects something it can bind to. Either store the result of `fun2` in an auxilliary variable or change `fun1` to either of the following:

```
int fun1(int z) // copy
int fun1(int const& z) // const ref
```

By the way, `void main` is not legal C++.